# Positioning <div>s using jQuery .animate and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

I'm trying to use jQuery to do some nice animations on my UI which is in turn built using Bootstrap.  I have two `<DIV>`s in my HTML: `id="fadein"` (which has `style="display:none"`) and `id="slidedown"`.  Here's my script:

```
<script language="javascript">
function doAnimations() {
  var height = $('#fadein').height();
  $('#slidedown').animate({top: height + "px"}, {duration: 1000});
  $('#fadein').delay(1000).fadeIn({duration: 1000});
};
function init() {
  setTimeout(doAnimations(), 500);
};
window.onload = init;
</script>
```

What I want to happen is that when the page is loaded, 500ms later the `<DIV>` `#slidedown` slides down by the amount of space that the `<DIV>` `#fadein` will occupy; then, when it's moved (by using `delay(1000)`, fade in the `<DIV>` `#fadein`.  What happens is that the `<DIV>` `#slidedown` does move down nicely, **but** immediately `#fadein` starts to appear it jumps down the page.  I suspect this is to do with the position of `#slidedown` being `position: relative` to it's parent object, and when the `#fadein` `<DIV>` starts to appear **that** becomes it's new parent.

My thoughts were to capture the `.offset()` of `#slidedown` when invoking the function and just before the `fadeIn()` method to reset the `.css` value of `top` to this value to anchor it in place - but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to best stop `#slidedown` moving any further when the `.animate` has completed?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK I fixed it :)  I used a function callback after the `.animate` completed and got it working.  The new function looks like:

```
function doAnimations() {
  var originalOffset = $('#slidedown').offset();
  var moveBy = parseInt($('#fadein').height());
  $('#slidedown').animate({top: moveBy + "px"}, 1000, function() {
    $('#slidedown').offset({top: parseInt(originalOffset.top), left: parseInt(originalOffset.left)});
    $('#fadein').fadeIn({duration: 1000});
  });
};
```

So why wasn't it working before?  It seems that using a time duration of `{duration: 1000}` stopped the function from being called but when I changed this to a simple numeric it worked and called the function when the `.animate` completed.  Odd.

If anyone has any more elegant solutions than this I'd love to hear them - I'm very much still learning this stuff!